# creating an array with a for statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to create Create an array containing the names of at least three (3) fast food items and then, using a ‘for’ loop, display the array name, index number, and food item as shown below.

```
             Fast Foods
             fastFoods[0] is pizza
             fastFoods[1] is burgers
             fastFoods[2] is french fries
```

I can get the array but not the for to display like this.

Comment: Display where? To the console? On an HTML page? In an alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Iterate over an array with for :**

each array has a [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property.Array indexing starts from 0 but length property starts count from 1.So in your for loop you have to set a condition which will iterate until the end of array is reached.[for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to iterate over an array has the following structure

```
   for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){  // in your case it will be fastfood.length
        //access elements here 
    }
```

**++**  is an increment operator.It will increase the value of i by one after each iteration.It is equivalent to `i=i+1;`

and inside for loop you can access the elements using the following structure

```
arrayName[index];
```

here **arrayName** is your array name( **in this case fastfood**) and index is the current **i** value;
so for your case it will be

```
fastfood[i]
```

**To create an array with for :**

first create a new array called fastfood

```
var fastfood=new Array()  //or
var fastfood=[]   // [] is a valid array notation
```

if you are goning to create an array using for loop you have to set a condition about how many elements you want to set in your array.For this case the structure will be

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){} // here n is your desired number;
```

inside the for loop you can have a [prompt method .](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt)It will allow you to enter a food element after each iteration.Prompt is not a good idea,but i assumed you are new to JS.Here is the structure:

```
fastfood[i]=prompt('enter food name');
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining and not just dumping code. That helps people to learn rather than just providing completed code without explanation to blindly meet some goal.

Comment: Yes thank you. This helped me understand a bit better what I should be doing. Just starting out with javascript. Trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 3):

```
var fastFood = ['pizza', 'burgers', 'french fries'];

for (var i = 0; i < fastFood.length; i++) {
  console.log('fastFood[' + i + '] is ' + fastFood[i]);
}
```